# Fastai get_preds gives me Permission Denied error

Tags: python, fast-ai

I have trained my model using `fine_tune()` but when I try to test the model

```
train_dls = learner.dls.test_dl(test_dir)
learner.get_preds(dl=train_dls,with_decoded=True)
```

against the test dataset I get an error: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:` on the `learner.get_preds()`

The dataset is the Stanford Dog Breed dataset, that I download, and unzip in the working directory of the project. It seems that I can't read the images in the test folder.

I've developed my code running as administrator, and inside an Anaconda notebook environment.